# Databricks - Error writing to Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I am trying to write data to Azure Synapse table with identity field with following code

**code on databricks**

```py
def get_jdbc_connection(host, sqlDatabase, user, password):
  jdbcHostname = "{}.database.windows.net".format(host)
  jdbc_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{}:1433;database={};user={}@{};password={};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;".format(jdbcHostname, sqlDatabase, user, host, password)
  url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{}:1433;database={};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;".format(jdbcHostname, sqlDatabase)
  return (jdbc_url,url )

def write_adw(spark, df_target_adw, jdbc_url, table, tempDir, option_mode, pre_Actions ):
    df_target_adw.write.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
        .option("url", jdbc_url) \
        .option("useAzureMSI", "true") \
        .option("preActions", pre_Actions) \
        .option("dbTable", table) \
        .option("tempDir", tempDir) \
        .mode(option_mode) \
        .save()
    
dftraffic = spark.sql('SELECT distinct SourceName\
              ,1 AS IsActiveRow \
             ,"Pipe-123" as pipelineId \
              ,current_timestamp as ADFCreatedDateTime \
              ,current_timestamp as ADFModifiedDateTime \
              from deltaTable')

#write to ADW
(jdbc_url, url_adw) = get_jdbc_connection(host, sqlDatawarehouse,user, password)
target_table = 'TargetTable_name'
option_mode= "append"
pre_Actions= " SELECT GETDATE()"
write_adw(spark, dftraffic, jdbc_url, target_table, tempDir, option_mode, pre_Actions )
```

**schema of target table on adw**

| Column Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| SourceSID | INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL |
| Source Name | VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL |
| IsRowActive | BIT NOT NULL |
| PipelineId | VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL |
| ADFCreatedDateTime | DATETIME NOT NULL |
| ADFModifiedDateTime | DATETIME NOT NULL |

**Configuration details on databricks**

> Databricks runtime 7.4 (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12)

**Error Message**

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o457.save.
> : com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWSideException: Azure Synapse Analytics failed to execute the JDBC query produced by the connector.
> Underlying SQLException(s):  - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An explicit value for the identity column in table can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

the code was working all fine on databricks runtime 6.4 Spark 2.4.5 and I am facing this error as soon I tried to upgrade dbk runtime.
How can I get this to work?

Comment: have you tried to add `SET IDENTITY_INSERT archive_table ON;` as `pre_Actions`

Comment: Let me try that and will update you.

Comment: @Idleguys did you got any solution to the problem?

Comment: no, this did not work as i need to turn "off" the identity_insert on the table after the inserts complete.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not having the extra row "1 AS IsActiveRow " .I dont see that in the Schema

```
dftraffic = spark.sql('SELECT distinct SourceName\
              ,1 AS IsActiveRow \
             ,"Pipe-123" as pipelineId \
              ,current_timestamp as ADFCreatedDateTime \
              ,current_timestamp as ADFModifiedDateTime \
              from deltaTable)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is typo in the above schema definition. Apologies! I do have "IsActiveRow" field on my target table.